# Getting an error running powershell command on server 2019, over an ssh connection

Tags: ssh, powershell

I thought I had a clever idea.

**The Challenge:**

I have a linux webserver that needs to manipulate excel files.
While there are many linux-commandline tools for editing excel files... none of them are suitable.
Those work on simple files, but if you have a human generated file that uses lots of fancy features, the linux-tools will screwup the excel formatting at the very least.

The one command line tool that hasn't screwed me so far is window's powershell.

**The plan:**

I installed the SSH server and Excel on a Windows 2019 box.
I ssh from the linux server to the windows server, and execute powershell commands.

**The problem:**
I get an error when trying to open a file with "powershell excel"
But I only get this error when I run the command over my ssh connection.   The exact same command/same user   works when run locally in a PS window.

(rrrrr = a valid excel file)

SSH experience:

[image]

Local PowerShell experience:

[image]

Any ideas?   Thought this was a "headless" command that would work in a headless environment.  Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot open an Excel interactive session over SSH, so this fails.
You should use non-interactive tools instead.

Manipulating Excel spreadsheets in possible directly in PowerShell by using the module
[Import-Excel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel),
described as:

> This PowerShell Module allows you to read and write Excel files without installing Microsoft Excel on your system. No need to bother with the cumbersome Excel COM-object. Creating Tables, Pivot Tables, Charts and much more has just become a lot easier.

Using this module is further described in James O'Neill's Blog:

- [Using the Import-Excel module: Part 1 Importing](https://jamesone111.wordpress.com/2017/12/05/using-the-import-excel-part-1-importing/)
- [Using the Import Excel module part 2: putting data into .XLSx files](https://jamesone111.wordpress.com/2017/12/11/using-the-import-excel-module-part-2-putting-data-into-xlsx-files/)
- [Using the import Excel Module: Part 3, Pivots and charts, data and calculations](https://jamesone111.wordpress.com/2017/12/12/using-the-import-excel-module-part-3-pivots-and-charts-data-and-calculations/)